# Draw arrow inside a datamaps using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, datamaps

I am new to **d3.js** , i am trying to create a custom map svg .

With some reference i did a custom map which is shown below.

[image: Arrow pointed at the bottom left of the page]

The code snippet for the above output is here.

https://jsfiddle.net/9kbp4h6j/

```js
"use strict"

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(100,50)")

svg.append("svg:defs")
  .append("svg:marker")
  .attr("id", "arrow")
  .attr("refX", 2)
  .attr("refY", 6)
  .attr("markerWidth", 13)
  .attr("markerHeight", 13)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2");


var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (point) {
    return point.lx;
  })
  .y(function (point) {
    return point.ly;
  });

function lineData(d) {
  // i'm assuming here that supplied datum 
  // is a link between 'source' and 'target'
  var points = [{
      lx: d.source.x,
      ly: d.source.y
    },
    {
      lx: d.target.x,
      ly: d.target.y
    }
  ];
  return line(points);
}

var path = svg.append("path")
  .data([{
    source: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    target: {
      x: 80,
      y: 80
    }
  }])
  .attr("class", "line")
  //.style("marker-end", "url(#arrow)")
  .attr("d", lineData);
//var arrow = svg.append("svg:path")
//.attr("d", "M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2");


console.log(d3.svg.symbol())

var arrow = svg.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-down")(10, 1));


arrow.transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
//.each("end", transition);


// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  var ps = path.getPointAtLength(0);
  var pe = path.getPointAtLength(l);
  var angl = Math.atan2(pe.y - ps.y, pe.x - ps.x) * (180 / Math.PI) - 90;
  var rot_tran = "rotate(" + angl + ")";
  return function (d, i, a) {
    console.log(d);

    return function (t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ") " + rot_tran;
    };
  };
}

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);


var bubble_map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('canada'),
  scope: 'canada',
  geographyConfig: {
    popupOnHover: true,
    highlightOnHover: true,
    borderColor: '#444',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    dataUrl: 'https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/canada.topo.json'
    //dataJson: topoJsonData
  },
  fills: {
    'MAJOR': '#306596',
    'MEDIUM': '#0fa0fa',
    'MINOR': '#bada55',
    defaultFill: '#dddddd'
  },
  data: {
    'JH': {
      fillKey: 'MINOR'
    },
    'MH': {
      fillKey: 'MINOR'
    }
  },
  setProjection: function (element) {
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      .center([-106.3468, 68.1304]) // always in [East Latitude, North Longitude]
      .scale(250)
      .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
    return {
      path: path,
      projection: projection
    };
  }
});

let bubbles = [{
    centered: "MB",
    fillKey: "MAJOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Manitoba"
  },
  {
    centered: "AB",
    fillKey: "MAJOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Alberta"
  },
  {
    centered: "NT",
    fillKey: "MAJOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Northwest Territories"
  },
  {
    centered: "NU",
    fillKey: "MEDIUM",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Nunavut"
  },
  {
    centered: "BC   ",
    fillKey: "MEDIUM",
    radius: 8,
    state: "British Columbia"
  },
  {
    centered: "QC",
    fillKey: "MINOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Québec"
  },
  {
    centered: "NB",
    fillKey: "MINOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "New Brunswick"
  }

]
// // ISO ID code for city or <state></state>
setTimeout(() => { // only start drawing bubbles on the map when map has rendered completely.
  bubble_map.bubbles(bubbles, {
    popupTemplate: function (geo, data) {
      return `<div class="hoverinfo">city: ${data.state}, Slums: ${data.radius}%</div>`;
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.line {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  fill: white;
}

circle {
  fill: red;
}
#marker {
 stroke: black;
 fill: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/datamaps.none.js"></script>
    <div id="canada" style="height: 600px; width: 900px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a marker which is attached to the body , but the actual output what i need is,

> 1. The arrow must be starting from the bubble shown in the image
> 2. It should end on some random directions so that a popup template box can be added to describe the actual location.

So at last the actual output what i need should look somewhat like this.

[image: Arrow pointed out from each and every location]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why not use  d3-tip http://bl.ocks.org/davegotz/bd54b56723c154d25eedde6504d30ad7 , arrow is an  overhead. this will contain arrow and will also suffice the tooltip requirement

Comment: @Aqua4 But i dont think it would be helpful in thisi scenario

Comment: @ShreyasAchar, I though that the animation you wanted to be on hover, is that why mine is not accepted? my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines can be individually customized by including 2 fields in data: `arrowDirectionAngle` and `arrowLineLength`.

```js
"use strict"

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (point) {
        return point.lx;
    })
    .y(function (point) {
        return point.ly;
    });

function lineData(d) {
    // i'm assuming here that supplied datum 
    // is a link between 'source' and 'target'
    var points = [{
        lx: d.source.x,
        ly: d.source.y
    },
    {
        lx: d.target.x,
        ly: d.target.y
    }
    ];
    return line(points);
}

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    var ps = path.getPointAtLength(0);
    var pe = path.getPointAtLength(l);
    var angl = Math.atan2(pe.y - ps.y, pe.x - ps.x) * (180 / Math.PI) - 90;
    var rot_tran = "rotate(" + angl + ")";
    return function (d, i, a) {
        //console.log(d);

        return function (t) {
            var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
            return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ") " + rot_tran;
        };
    };
}

var bubble_map = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('canada'),
    scope: 'canada',
    geographyConfig: {
        popupOnHover: true,
        highlightOnHover: true,
        borderColor: '#444',
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        dataUrl: 'https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/canada.topo.json'
        //dataJson: topoJsonData
    },
    fills: {
        'MAJOR': '#306596',
        'MEDIUM': '#0fa0fa',
        'MINOR': '#bada55',
        defaultFill: '#dddddd'
    },
    data: {
        'JH': {
            fillKey: 'MINOR'
        },
        'MH': {
            fillKey: 'MINOR'
        }
    },
    setProjection: function (element) {
        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([-106.3468, 68.1304]) // always in [East Latitude, North Longitude]
            .scale(250)
            .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
        return {
            path: path,
            projection: projection
        };
    }
});

let bubbles = [{
    centered: "MB",
    fillKey: "MAJOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Manitoba",
    arrowDirectionAngle: 90,
    arrowLineLength: 120
},
{
    centered: "AB",
    fillKey: "MAJOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Alberta",
    arrowDirectionAngle: 90,
    arrowLineLength: 100
},
{
    centered: "NT",
    fillKey: "MAJOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Northwest Territories",
    arrowDirectionAngle: 180,
    arrowLineLength: 130
},
{
    centered: "NU",
    fillKey: "MEDIUM",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Nunavut",
    arrowDirectionAngle: -25,
    arrowLineLength: 80
},
{
    centered: "BC   ",
    fillKey: "MEDIUM",
    radius: 8,
    state: "British Columbia",
    arrowDirectionAngle: 125,
    arrowLineLength: 65
},
{
    centered: "QC",
    fillKey: "MINOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "Québec",
    arrowDirectionAngle: -25,
    arrowLineLength: 70
},
{
    centered: "NB",
    fillKey: "MINOR",
    radius: 8,
    state: "New Brunswick",
    arrowDirectionAngle: 65,
    arrowLineLength: 50
}

]


function renderArrows(targetElementId) {
    let svgRoot = d3.select("#" + targetElementId).select("svg");

    svgRoot.append("svg:defs")
        .append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", "arrow")
        .attr("refX", 2)
        .attr("refY", 6)
        .attr("markerWidth", 13)
        .attr("markerHeight", 13)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2");

    let linesGroup = svgRoot.append("g");

    linesGroup.attr("class", "lines");

    let bubbleElements = svgRoot.selectAll(".datamaps-bubble")[0];

    bubbleElements.forEach(function (bubbleElement) {
        let xPosition = bubbleElement.cx.baseVal.value;
        let yPosition = bubbleElement.cy.baseVal.value;
        let datum = d3.select(bubbleElement).datum();

        let degree = datum.arrowDirectionAngle;
        let radius = datum.arrowLineLength;
        let theta = degree * Math.PI / 180;

        let path = linesGroup.append("path")
            .data([{
                source: {
                    x: xPosition,
                    y: yPosition
                },
                target: {
                    x: xPosition + radius * Math.cos(theta),
                    y: yPosition + radius * Math.sin(theta)
                }
            }])
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
            .style("fill", "white")
            //.style("marker-end", "url(#arrow)")
            .attr("d", lineData);


        let arrow = svgRoot.append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-down")(10, 1));


        arrow.transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .ease("linear")
            .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))

        var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

        path
            .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

    });
}

// // ISO ID code for city or <state></state>
setTimeout(() => { // only start drawing bubbles on the map when map has rendered completely.
    bubble_map.bubbles(bubbles, {
        popupTemplate: function (geo, data) {
            return `<div class="hoverinfo">city: ${data.state}, Slums: ${data.radius}%</div>`;
        }
    });

    renderArrows("canada");

}, 1000);
```

```css
.line {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    fill: white;
}

circle {
    fill: red;
}

#marker {
    stroke: black;
    fill: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/datamaps.none.js"></script>
    <div id="canada" style="height: 600px; width: 900px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lines add separately using path line and arrow, and using mouse event you can manipulate the location of the path based on the center of the hovered bubble, also for the tooltip you can use `d3.select()` to get the `div` of thee tooltip and change its `innerHTML` attribute to display a message.

Here is a working solution:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(100,50)")

      svg.append("svg:defs")
        .append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", "arrow") 
        .attr("refX", 2)
        .attr("refY", 6)
        .attr("markerWidth", 13)
        .attr("markerHeight", 13)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2");


      var line = d3.svg.line()
                  .x( function(point) { return point.lx; })
                  .y( function(point) { return point.ly; });

      function lineData(d){
        // i'm assuming here that supplied datum 
        // is a link between 'source' and 'target'
        var points = [
            {lx: d.source.x, ly: d.source.y},
            {lx: d.target.x, ly: d.target.y}
        ];
        return line(points);
      }


  // Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
  function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    var ps = path.getPointAtLength(0);
    var pe = path.getPointAtLength(l);
    var angl = Math.atan2(pe.y - ps.y, pe.x - ps.x) * (180 / Math.PI) - 90;
    var rot_tran = "rotate(" + angl + ")";
    return function(d, i, a) {
      return function(t) {
        var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
        if(t < 0.111) {
          return '';
        }
        return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ") " + rot_tran;
      };
    };
  }




    var bubble_map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('canada'),
        scope: 'canada',
        geographyConfig: {
            popupOnHover: true,
            highlightOnHover: true,
            borderColor: '#444',
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            dataUrl: 'https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/canada.topo.json'
            //dataJson: topoJsonData
        },
        fills: {
            'MAJOR': '#306596',
            'MEDIUM': '#0fa0fa',
            'MINOR': '#bada55',
            defaultFill: '#dddddd'
        },
        data: {
            'JH': { fillKey: 'MINOR' },
            'MH': { fillKey: 'MINOR' }
        },
        setProjection: function (element) {
              var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([-106.3468, 68.1304]) // always in [East Latitude, North Longitude]
            .scale(250)
            .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);

            var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
            return { path: path, projection: projection };
        }
    });

    let bubbles = [
        {
            centered: "MB",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 8,
            state: "Manitoba"
        },
        {
            centered: "AB",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 8,
            state: "Alberta"
        },
        {
            centered: "NT",
            fillKey: "MAJOR",
            radius: 8,
            state: "Northwest Territories"
        },
        {
            centered: "NU",
            fillKey: "MEDIUM",
            radius: 8,
            state: "Nunavut"
        },
        {
            centered: "BC   ",
            fillKey: "MEDIUM",
            radius: 8,
            state: "British Columbia"
        },
        {
            centered: "QC",
            fillKey: "MINOR",
            radius: 8,
            state: "Québec"
        },
        {
            centered: "NB",
            fillKey: "MINOR",
            radius: 8,
            state: "New Brunswick"
        }

    ];
    // ISO ID code for city or <state></state>
    setTimeout(() => { // only start drawing bubbles on the map when map has rendered completely.
        bubble_map.bubbles(bubbles, {
            popupTemplate: function (geo, data) {
                return ``;
                // return `<div class="hoverinfo">city: ${data.state}, Slums: ${data.radius}%</div>`;
            }
        });
        const line_data = [{source: {x:0, y:0}, target: {x:100, y:100}}];
        var path = d3.select('.datamap').append("path")
          .data(line_data)
          .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", lineData);

        var arrow = d3.select('.datamap').append("svg:path")
          .attr('d', null)
          .attr('class', 'tri');
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => { // only start drawing bubbles on the map when map has rendered completely.
        const svg = d3.select('.datamap');
        var circles = d3.selectAll('circle');
        
        var state_data = d3.selectAll('circle').data();


        circles.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
          if(!document.querySelectorAll(".active").length) {
            let x = circles[0][i].cx.baseVal.value;
            let y = circles[0][i].cy.baseVal.value+8;
            
            state_info = state_data[i];

            const line_data = [{source: {x, y}, target: {x , y : y + 100}}];
            if(i === 2) {
              line_data[0].source.x = line_data[0].source.x - 8;
              line_data[0].source.y = line_data[0].source.y - 8;
              line_data[0].target.y = line_data[0].source.y;
              line_data[0].target.x = line_data[0].source.x - 150;
            }
            if(i === 3) {
              line_data[0].source.x = line_data[0].source.x + 8;
              line_data[0].source.y = line_data[0].source.y - 8;
              line_data[0].target.y = line_data[0].source.y;
              line_data[0].target.x = line_data[0].source.x + 100;
            }

            if(i === 4) {
              line_data[0].source.x = line_data[0].source.x - 8;
              line_data[0].source.y = line_data[0].source.y - 8;
              line_data[0].target.y = line_data[0].source.y + 50;
              line_data[0].target.x = line_data[0].source.x / 2;
            }

            if(i === 5) {
              line_data[0].source.x = line_data[0].source.x + 8;
              line_data[0].source.y = line_data[0].source.y - 8;
              line_data[0].target.y = line_data[0].source.y;
              line_data[0].target.x = line_data[0].source.x  + 100;
            }

            var path = d3.select('path.line');
            path.data(line_data)
              .attr("class", "line")
              .attr("d", lineData);

            var arrow = d3.select('.tri');
            
            arrow.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-down")(10,1));
            arrow.interrupt();
            arrow.transition()
              .duration(2000)
              .ease("linear")
              .attr("class", "tri")
              .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
              .each("end", () => {
                d3.select('.datamaps-hoverover')
                .style('display','block')
                .style('left', (line_data[0].target.x + 10) + "px")
                .style('top', (line_data[0].target.y + 10) +"px")
                .html('<div class="hoverinfo"><strong> this is from the custom tooltip: city: ' + state_info.state + ', Slum: ' + state_info.radius + '%</strong></div>');
              });

              var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
              path.interrupt();
              path
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
                .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
                .transition()
                  .duration(2000)        
                  .ease("linear")
                  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
            
            }
        });

        circles.on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
          d3.select('path.line').attr('d', null);
          d3.select('path.tri').attr('d', null);
          d3.select('.datamaps-hoverover')
            .style('display','none')
            .html('');
        })

      }, 1500);
```

```css
.line {
  stroke: blue !important;
  fill: blue
}

.tri {
  stroke: blue !important;
  fill: blue
}

circle {
  fill: red;
}

#marker {
  stroke: black;
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/Anujarya300/bubble_maps/master/data/geography-data/datamaps.none.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="canada" style="height: 600px; width: 900px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```